# how to insert data and label from api into data set to display chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

i'm new to vuejs and i am not getting how to insert data and label from API data into data set and label to display multi line chart,
i have given data model below that's my API output data.

I searched on the internet and I have tried so many ways and I didn't find the solution. Here goes my codes:..................................................................................................................................................

```
    <script>
      data() {
      return {
        labels: [ ],
         result:'',
         datasets: [
        {
          label: "Data One",
          data: [ ]
        },
        {
          label: "Data Two",
          data: [ ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },

    methods: {
    updateChart() {
      var self=this;
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:5000/api/" )
        .then(res => {
          // proccess the response
         //  this.datasets[0].data = res.data[0];
       //  self.result = res.data;
       //  console.log(self.result )
          this.renderChart(
            {
              labels: [],
              datasets: this.datasets
            },
            { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
          );
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error:", error);
        });
      }
     }
   </script>

   //below is my api data
        [
    [
      "2014-01-01", 
      "2014-01-01", 
      "2014-01-02", 
      "2014-01-03", 
      "2014-01-04"
    ], 
    [
      10002200, 
      10379971, 
      10123749, 
      10712250, 
      13923904
    ], 
    [
      14412854, 
      12412854, 
      14415554, 
      12415554, 
      16412854
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: How are you trying to aggregate the data? You show an API response with 2 multi dimentional arrays, but simple charts only accept a single array of values. Are you looking to make the `labels` the `dates` and group the values under those dates?

Comment: [
  ["2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-02","2014-01-03", "2014-01-04"], 
  [  1 , 11 , 12 , 10 , 4  ],
   [14,15,13,12,1] 
    ]

Comment: bro for above data model...how can  insert in to datasets and label////

Comment: first array is for label and second and third array for dataset

Comment: Can you update the question please? What you pasted in the comments as your API response does not pair with what you have in your question as your API response.

Comment: ya i updated response from API

Comment: multi line chart .

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following given your API response:

```
axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/api/" )
    .then(res => {
        //labels are the first element in the array
        this.labels = res.data[0]

        //remove the first element from the array so we don't pollute our datasets
        res.data.shift()

        //destructure the array and reduce it
        this.datasets = [...res.data].reduce((carry, arr) => {
          //push our dataset object into the carry
          carry.push({
            label: '',
            data: arr
          })

          return carry
        },[])

        //build the chart
        this.renderChart({
            labels: this.labels,
            datasets: this.datasets
        })
    })
```

I've annotated the above code for clarity. I don't see any way to give you the `label` for the individual datasets, though.

Comment: @Pavan Fixed that. My bad.